# Photo Swap (can't link photos)

Tags: javascript, image, photo

I've tried to add links to my photos on my photo swapper in javascript.

My photo swapper:

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript1.1">
        <!--
            var image1=new Image() 
            image1.src="http://i.imgur.com/NEBlLov.jpg" 
            var image2=new Image() 
            image2.src="http://i.imgur.com/e0y1EGg.jpg"
            var image3=new Image() 
            image3.src="http://i.imgur.com/45Thw6n.jpg"
        //-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JYYPkmK.jpg" name="slide" width=748 height=100>
        <script>
        <!--
            //variable that will increment through the images
            var step=1
            function slideit(){
                //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
                if (!document.images) return document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
                if (step<3) step++
                else step=1

                //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
                setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
            }
            slideit()
        //-->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what I tried to fix the problem. I have tried to use the onclick. However, it didn't work either.

Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
    if (!image1.src)
    <a href="/donate/"></a>
    return
    if (!image2.src)
    <a href="/vote/"></a>
    return
    if (!image3.src)
    <a href="/forums/"></a>
    return
</script>
```

Comment: So you're trying to say that if `image1.src` doesn't exist, it should go to donate, and if `image2.src` doesn't exist, it should go to vote? I'm thinking that's the opposite of what you really want to do.

Comment: Lmao, I just realized that. Thanks, now I feel stupid.

Comment: Am I check for the correct varriable? Cause when I removed the '!', it still won't work.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle you can link to? It's kind of hard to tell just by looking what this is doing.

Comment: No, I just write the code and run it on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code. I modified the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript1.1">
    <!--
        var image1=new Image() 
        image1.src="http://i.imgur.com/NEBlLov.jpg" 
        var image2=new Image() 
        image2.src="http://i.imgur.com/e0y1EGg.jpg"
        var image3=new Image() 
        image3.src="http://i.imgur.com/45Thw6n.jpg"
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JYYPkmK.jpg" id="slide" width=748 height=100>
    <script>
    <!--
        //variable that will increment through the images
        var step=1
        function slideit(){
            document.getElementById("slide").src=eval("image"+step+".src");
            if (step<3) step++
            else step=1

            //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
            setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
        }
        slideit()
    //-->
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -4):

Remove the bangs from your code; it's never going to evaluate correctly.

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
    if (image1.src)
    <a href="/donate/"></a>
    return
    if (image2.src)
    <a href="/vote/"></a>
    return
    if (image3.src)
    <a href="/forums/"></a>
    return
</script>
```